# C# Multithreaded/ Parallel start and stop of hosted services in worker service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await

In my application I am using a dotnet worker service template (.NET6). In my `program.cs` I add multiple `IHostedService` via `AddSingleton` method. The number of services I add may vary between a few and dozens. Every worker (IHostedService) I add inherits from the `BackgroundService` class.
In my worker I then override the `StopAsync` method. This looks like below:

```
        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("Name", Name))
            {
                try
                {
                    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // From here on we exit
                    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Stopwatch exitWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    Logger?.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Start exit procedures");
                    await ExitProcessor().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Logger?.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Execute procedures finished in <{elapsedMilliseconds}> ms", exitWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                    exitWatch.Stop();

                    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // And signal to the host
                    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                    await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger?.Log(LogLevel.Error, "{ex}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

The ExitProcessor methods basically looks like this:

```
private async Task ExitProcessor()
{
    await ExitSource().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await Exit().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await ExitSink().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

When doing a graceful shutdown of my application I was expecting the StopAsync to hit all the workers at the same time. However this does not seem to be the case. The stop of the whole worker service seems to be synchronously.

This is becoming a problem the more IHostedServices I add as the shutdown time adds up and it might sometime hit the maximum shutdown time of e.g. a systemd service.

I have the feeling I am doing something wrong with either the way I set up the services or with the async and await stuff.

Comment: What does `ExitProcessor()` do? Looks like the relevant code would be in there? The snippet as of now looks ok to me.

Comment: @Fildor Edited my question for you. Basically it goes down very deep during the exit procedures, however they are all async await.

Comment: Could _those_ run concurrently? If so, you could do `await Task.WhenAll( ExitSource(), Exit(), ExitSink() );` - That should reduce runtime (with a little overhead) to the slowest of them.

Comment: `async` does not mean parallel, it means it won't hang on IO bound task

Comment: `expecting the StopAsync to hit all the workers at the same time.` the expectation was wrong. `StopAsync` is only called when the application terminates and *doesn't* run in a separate thread. It's async to allow your code to call async operations. `StartAsync` and `ExecuteAsync` don't run in separate threads either. If the methods never yield, they'll complete synchronously. There's no synchronization context (no UI or ASP.NET Core request) in a hosted service so `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't have any effect

Comment: Panagiotis is correct. There is [an option coming for concurrent shutdown in .net 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostoptions.servicesstopconcurrently?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0), though.

Comment: MSDN mentions, in case of many workers they are started synchronously, so it's important that their `StartAsync()` returns qiuckly; according to OP's description they stopped syncronously too. I am leading to this: what if to release a thread asap, ie using `await Task.Yield` in every worker's `StopAsync`  implementation? Never tested it.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. This already helped. In addition to the comments about my assumption I also quite like what @StephenCleary said. I mean .NET 8 is around the corner ...